# Undefined reference to `SDL_Init'

Tags: c++, sdl

after the last 2 days, I returned to OpenGL to get it working. Almost got it as well. (Why do I say almost? It made a window once) Problem is now it won't work at all. Something to do with Undefined references. Below is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include "map.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_EVENTS);
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Tycoon Example",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,640,480,SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_GLContext glcontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    if (window == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    Game_Map world = Game_Map(20,20); //Ignore this. It is class that is included in map.h

    return 0; 
}
```

I am unsure what is causing this. I have kept the code at a basic complexity to cut down external influences. Can you think of what may cause this? My laptop seems to be x64 but I am unsure as there are program folders for x86 as well. But my focus is solving what this error is meaning and what could cause it. Any advice?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix?

Comment: Had a read through and I think I understand what the error is. Now I'm wondering how does it relate to my situation?

Comment: You should check all of the answers there.

Comment: @JeremyBeare: You should include your compile line in your question. You're probably missing something like `-lsdl`.

Comment: @ Zeta - I haven't heard of this compile line. Where would I find it in Code Blocks? Actually, a better question would be what is a compile line?

Comment: NVM, is this it?

mingw32-g++.exe  -o "bin\Debug\Tycoon Example.exe" obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\map.o   -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lopengl32 -lglew32 -lglu32
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `SDL_main':